# Обратиться к объекту созданного программно

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

Создаю программно `UIButton`

```
let btn2 = UIButton(type: .custom) as UIButton
        btn2.backgroundColor = .blue
        btn2.setTitle("3", for: .normal)
        btn2.tag = 3
        btn2.frame = CGRect(x: 131, y: 234, width: 35, height: 30)
        btn2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tupped), for: .touchUpInside)
        num2 = btn2.tag
        self.view.addSubview(btn2)

    }
```

Как обратиться к нему через

```
  @objc func tupped(){
           lab2.text = String(num)

        }
```

Comment: А что вы хотите с кнопкой сделать? Какая у вас цель?

Comment: Хочу, чтобы при нажатии, она меняла свой цвет Background и менялось название ( вместе "3" - появлялись "Х"). С переменой к которой я присвоил Таg все нормально. А вот обратиться уже к конкретно к свойствам кнопки не получается

Answer (score 0):

```
@objc func tupped(){
  btn2.setTitle("X", for: .normal)
  btn2.backgroundColor = UIColor.red()    
}
```

Comment: Я так пытался делать. Проблема в том, что он не видит ее что-ли. Так как пишет «use of unresolved identifier ’btn ‘»

Comment: Если вы btn2 обьявили и определили в методе, то она является локальной для этого метода. За пределами метода объявите var btn2: UIButton! а когда определяете btn2 уберите let.

Comment: Да!! Точно!! Спасибо огромное !

Comment: Как принять ? Я Около кода поставил единичку . Это не то ?)